# Combine multiple rows into object properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, linq

I have a SQL query that returns rows from a usage log like:

```
ActionID    ActionType      ActionDetail    ActionDetailValue
1           SEARCH          Query           jones
1           SEARCH          ResultCount     156
2           DOCUMENT_VIEW   Title           All About Mister Jones
2           DOCUMENT_VIEW   DocumentID      EKDJF34
```

i.e. each action taken by a user may have multiple rows with different details about the action taken. At the moment, this is represented in C# as:

```
IEnumerable<ActionItem>

public class ActionItem
{
    public int ActionID { get; set; }
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
    public string ActionDetail { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I need to somehow combine rows with the same id and type. Ultimately I will want to return a JSON object along the lines of:

```
var trailItems = {"trailitems": [
    {"ActionID": "1", "ActionType": "SEARCH", "Query": "jones", "ResultCount" : "156"},
    {"ActionID": "2", "ActionType": "DOCUMENT_VIEW", "Title": "All About Mister Jones", "DocumentID" : "EKDJF34"}
]};
```

Seems like a job for LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not develop the Json part too much, I think you would be able to handle it when you have a good enough data structure. You could try this:

```
var grouped = 
    from a in actions
    group a by new { a.ActionID, a.ActionType } 
    into g
    select new 
    { 
        g.Key.ActionID, 
        g.Key.ActionType, 
        Values = 
            (from x in g
             select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.ActionDetail, x.Value))
            .ToDictionary()
    };
```

if you try to build json from this with no further processing you will obtain something like this:

```
[
    {"ActionID":1,"ActionType":"SEARCH","Values":{"Query":"jones","ResultCount":"156"}},
    {"ActionID":2,"ActionType":"DOCUMENT_VIEW","Values":{"Title":"All About Mister Jones","DocumentID":"EKDJF34"}}
]
```

which is not exactly what you are looking for but it's quite near, and maybe it would be even better to be processed because it separates the 'key' from the values.